# What are the eigenfunctions of the operators $M_1 f(x) = xf(x)$ and $M_2 f(x) = x^2f(x)$?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $H = L^2([1,2])$ and consider the multiplication operators
$$
\begin{align}
M_1 f(x) &= xf(x) \\
M_2 f(x) &= x^2f(x).
\end{align}
$$
I know that $M_1$ has spectrum $\sigma_1 = [1,2]$ and $M_2$ has spectrum $\sigma_2 = [2,4]$ but what are the eigenfuctions that correspond to elements of the spectrums of $M_1$ and $M_2$?

Comment: They don’t have eigenfunctions. This is continuous spectrum, not point spectrum.

Comment: Do they have something analogous to eigenfunctions?

Comment: To each $ \mu \in \sigma_1$ there is a sequence $(f_n)$ in $H$ such that $||f_n||_2=1$ for all $n$ and $||( \mu I-M_1)f_n||_2 \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $M_1$:

if $ \mu \in \sigma_1$, $f \in H$ and $M_1f= \mu f$, then $(x- \mu)f(x)=0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. This gives $f=0$ a.e.

Consequence: $M_1$ has no eigenvalues !